# how to set attrs array to undefined in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I would like to set `attrs` to undefined from unit test, I tried few approaches and didn't get to set it to `undefined`. Below is my directive:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('someElement', function () {

var directive = {};

directive.restrict = 'E';
directive.replace = true;
directive.transclude = true;

directive.templateUrl = function (element, attrs) {
  var template = '';
  if(attrs) { // would like to invoke this in unit test and set it to `undefined`
    //do something
  }
  return template;
};

directive.scope = {...};

directive.compile = function () {
    //do something
return directive;
});
```

here is a the snippet, assume that directive is compiled and `$digest` cycle is triggered. here is what i got in the test:

```
it('should set attrs to undefined', function () {
    .....
    attrs = {};
    scope.$apply();
    expect(attrs).toBeUndefined(); // I want this to pass!!
});
```

Comment: 1st what are you going to achieve by doing it..then how do you get values for isolated scope

Comment: TBH it doesn't really matter what I'm trying to achieve, I wanted to ask if it's possible and how!

Comment: did you tried to make it `if(attrs) attrs={}`?

Comment: i want to set attrs value to `undefined` from unit test!

Comment: then I'd suggest you to add element without `attribute` & `compile` it in your test like `<my-dir></my-dir>`

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I'm doing but it the length is set to 1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79800/discussion-between-pankajparkar-and-simple-solution).

Comment: You assign an empty object to `attrs` and expect it to be `undefined`?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get original directive factory from within a test and modify it before compiling and even unit-test it's methods, but I'am not sure if this approach to test directives is right.
[If you take a look at the source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.3.16/src/ng/compile.js#L790), you can see that angular registers each directive as a factory with a 'Directive' suffix. Knowing that, you can inject your directive factory in a test:

```
var directiveFactory;

beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {
    // considering that you directive is called 'myEl'
    directiveFactory = $injector.get('myElDirective')[0];
}));
```

Here one should use `[0]`'s because factories are returned in array - that's the way angular deals with directives, which have an option `multiElement: true` (if you have this option enabled, then maybe this trick won't work).

As a result the variable `directiveFactory` now holds an actual factory, so original `templateUrl` could be replaced and fake called with undefined attrs:

```
it('should do something when attrs are undefined', function () {

    var template = '<my-el></my-el>';

    // backup original function
    var originalTemplateUrl = directiveFactory.templateUrl;

    // replace with fake one
    directiveFactory.templateUrl = function (element, attrs) {
        // call original function with undefined attrs
        return originalTemplateUrl(element, undefined);
    };

   var element = $compile(template)($scope);
   $scope.$digest();

   // expect whatever
});
```

Now you could examine calls to your directive's original `templateUrl` and find out that `attrs` are `undefined`.

[See the plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gjYTvelzYt4Rj5Avb2U6?p=preview)